# Multidimensional char array in c

Tags: arrays, char

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char a[10][10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a[i] = "dfsdfsdfsdf";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
    }
}
```

I want to fill up the array with strings. This works in PHP. What I'm doing wrong in C?

Comment: You are confusing pointers and arrays. (and non-modifiable lvalues with modifiable lvalues.)

Comment: @mbratch No, that would be `const char *[10]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using character arrays to represent your string you need to use strcpy function:

```
strcpy(a[i], "dfsdfsdfsdf");
```

You probably should do some length checking of your varaible to make sure that you don't overrun your buffer:

```
strncpy(a[i], "dfsdfsdfsdf", 10);
```

It might be a good idea to brush up on pointers in C if you are going to be doing any amount of coding.  Understanding pointers are critical to mastering (or even using) the C language.